# NodeJS MySQL asynchronous calls prevent process from exiting

Tags: mysql, node.js, asynchronous, es6-promise

I have a configuration array that contains objects. Based on the properties in those objects a query is build for every line in the array. So the amount of queries being executed is not a set number.

The data from those queries then needs to be inserted into another table. I have written some code that performs this action, but I am having some problems with the asynchronous behavior of NodeJS. Because the MySQL calls are performed asynchronous, the NodeJS process is not exiting correctly. If I close the process myself at the end of the script, not all the MySQL calls are processed.

I suspect that I will have to use promises somewhere, but I am not that familiar with them.

Here is what I have already. It is currently written in a very synchronous way, but that is what I'm currently most familiar with.

```js
    require('dotenv').config();

    const mysql = require('mysql');
    const db = mysql.createConnection({
        host: process.env.DB_HOST,
        user: process.env.DB_USER,
        password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
        database: process.env.DB_DATABASE,
    });

    let items = [
            {"type": "A", "col1": "test"},
            {"type": "B", "col1": "lorem"}
    ];

    let lastId = 0;

    for (let item of items) {
        console.log(item);
        let query = 'SELECT * FROM testtable1 WHERE id > ? ';
        let queryParams = [lastId];

        for (let itemProp in item) {
            if (item.hasOwnProperty(itemProp)) {
                query += ' AND ' + itemProp + ' = ?';
                queryParams.push(item[itemProp]);
            }
        }
        console.log(db.format(query, queryParams));
        db.query(query, queryParams, (err, results, fields) => {
            if (err) throw err;
            if (results.length > 0) {
                for (let row of results) {
                    let rowData = {
                        col1: row.col1,
                        col2: row.col2
                    };
                    db.query('INSERT INTO testtable2 SET ?', rowData, (err, res) => {})
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as your connection is open to the MySQL server, the program won't exit.
You have to call `db.end()` in order to close the connection and allow the program to exit. See documentation here: https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql/blob/master/Readme.md#terminating-connections

Comment: But the question is, where do I place that db.end()? It has to be called when all queries have been enqueued, but as the amount of inserts is variable I guess I have to add some extra logic to detect when it is in the last loop of the for loop that loops through my items and when it is queueing the last insert in that last loop?

Comment: `db.end(function(err) {
  // The connection is terminated now
});`

Place it at after the for loop.

From Docs: 
`This will make sure all previously enqueued queries are still before sending a COM_QUIT packet to the MySQL server. If a fatal error occurs before the COM_QUIT packet can be sent, an err argument will be provided to the callback, but the connection will be terminated regardless of that.`

Comment: If I place it at the end, the INSERT statements can't be enqueued anymore because it closes the connection after the 1st SELECT statements have been executed.
`{ Error: Cannot enqueue Query after invoking quit.`

Answer (score 0):

So what I eventually ended up doing was creating a promise for every item in the for loop and push them to an array and then use the follow code to make sure all the promises where resolved before ending the database connection:

`Promise.all(promises).then(() => db.end());`